# How do I move this method-decorator pattern inside a class?

Tags: python, oop, python-decorators

Currently, I'm using a decorator to dynamically add methods from a class into a list; this way I can iterate over all of them at the same time when I need to, and I don't have manually add each of them at once:

```
predicates_list = []
def predicate(func):
    predicates_list.append(func)
    return func

class Person(object):
    @predicate
    def name_is_bill(self, name):
        return True if name == 'bill' else False

    def test_everything(self, tester):
        if any(predicate(name) for predicate in predicates_list:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

However, it doesn't make sense to have the decorating function and the list outside the scope of the Person class — only the Person class or its subclasses will use it. I've had no luck trying to make the decorator function a class method or a static method.

As a class method I get errors about needing two arguments. (That error makes sense, but do I need to pass `cls` or `self` as the first argument in the decorator? If so, how?)

As a static method, I don't have access to the class's properties. I could specify the name of the class in the decorator function, but I'll run into problems if I need to subclass Person.

There must be an elegant way to do this, but I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you're using looks correct. Most of the examples in the official [Python Decorator Library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary) use the same pattern you've adopted - decorator definition outside the class. See, for instance, the [Property Definition](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Property_Definition) example.

Comment: Well, I still say it's ugly and it pollutes my global namespace unnecessarily, but I submit to the will of the majority.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't disagree with you :) As a Pythonista, you know the language is often practical at the expense of things like beauty.